Reading binary data from serial port instrument
Intro
I would like to retrieve binary data from an instrument (SR620) using RS-232. The data is an histogram made of 250 bins. The python program I did works well when no data is acquired (I get 250 zeros), but as soon I actually start a measurement, the output is weird and I cannot use it. I will explain the data acquisition, the structure of the binary data and give a short version of the program with all relevant elements. Then I describe the output, and the error I get, the troubleshouting I did.
I understood that the problem came from a conversion of number above 127 being wrong see edit 4
My questions are :

are there another commands I could/should use to retrieve the binary data ?
is this related to the other commands, the algorithm, the device etc ?
where does the problem comes from, the program, the device itself ?

The result histogram I am expecting. Some periodic signal for three periods and then zeros in the last 2.5 us.

Data acquisition
I connect to the Time-to-Amplitude Converter (TAC) SR620 using the pyvisa module in python. I can set the instrument properly (set values of parameters, measurement mode ...). Everything in the front panel changes accordingly. I connect using this
rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
## Connecting to counter
TAC = rm.open_resource(self.TAC_address,
            baud_rate = 19200,
            data_bits = 8,
            stop_bits = StopBits(20),
            parity    = Parity(0))

In this experiment, I count the delays between a reference and an event on a detector (typically in the range of microseconds). I want N_Samples samples and retrieve the histogram of the delays. I start the measurement with TAC.write("STRT"). Note that when I collect the histogram directly in integer from the machine (using the dedicated function HSPT) it works well, but it is 'slow'. In binary this is much faster, but it is 'buggy'.
Data structure
To get my histogram in binary format I use the dedicated command XHST. The documentation tells us

XHST? j
The XHST? query returns section j (j=0 to 9) of the histogram
display as 4 byte binary integers least significant byte first. Each
section consists of the data for 25 histogram points (100 bytes total
plus terminator). There is no separator between successive points.
If the rs232 interface is being used an 8 bit data word must be chosen
to correctly transmit this data. The data returned is binned into 250
bins- not the number set by the front panel. This command allows one
to rapidly read the entire contents of the histogram display. If the
histogram is blank the illegal numbars -0 are returned.

So from there I understand I have to collect 10 sections made of 25 4-byte integers in binary. With a terminator (\r\n) in the end of each section that I remove not to mix integers with '\r\n'. The base fot this step is for j in range(0,10): data = TAC.query("XHST? "+str(j)).
Program
## imports
import pyvisa
from pyvisa.constants import StopBits, Parity
import struct
import time

## Connecting to counter
rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
TAC = rm.open_resource(self.TAC_address,
                baud_rate = 19200,
                data_bits = 8,
                stop_bits = StopBits(20),
                parity    = Parity(0))

## Setting parameters
TAC.write(f"SCLR")  ## clear measurement and display
TAC.write(f"WAIT 2") ## 2*2 ms delay between words
TAC.write(f"MODE 0") # 0 time mode
TAC.write(f"SIZE 10000") # number of samples
TAC.write(f"GSCL 2,250")  # number of bins

## Starting measurement (acquisition)
TAC.write("SRCE 0") # Input A
TAC.write(f"SCEN 1") # 1 single acquisition
TAC.write(f"AUTM 0") # no auto restart
TAC.write("STRT")

## Wait for the end of measurement
state = 0
while state != 1:
    state = int(TAC.query("*STB? 0"))
    ## returns 0 as long as measurement in progress
    print(f'State : {state}')
    time.sleep(5)

## retrieve data
self.meanlist = [] # result is stored here
for j in range(0,10):
    data = TAC.query("XHST? "+str(j))
    time.sleep(0.1)
    data = data.rstrip("\r\n") # remove terminator to not mix integers and \r\n
    data = data.encode() # convert to bytes
    print(data)
    # data = struct.unpack("<25i", data) # unpack as 25 4-byte integers
    # have to comment it otherwise I have struct.error
    self.meanlist.append(data)


Output without start measurement
Each print(data) gives
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

Which is the right thing, 25 4-byte integers. From that I say that my program works. In the end I can reconstitute my 250 bins histogram. It is all zero of course because I never started the acquisition.
But then if I make an acquisition first it does not make sense.
Output with start measurement
The print(data) in the for loop gives
b'\x08\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00'
b'\t\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x00\x00\x00'

Description of the error
If the line data = struct.unpack("<25i", data) is not commented I get the error struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 100 bytes.
This is why I print the data, and you can see the length of each output is different, also there are some \r, \n and '\t' sneaking into the output, which is weird. When redoing, the length are different, sometimes there is even empty outputs and also a complete one from time to time.
Some more (inefficient) troubleshooting
I have two different SR620 TAC that have the same weird behaviour. I tried to add delays, pauses, to change bit parity, encoding but always have this behaviour.
How can this be possible ? Where can it come from ? I start an acquisition, wait for the acquisition to be complete, then ask for the output. Output looks like it is cut before being complete. And why those extra characters showing up from time to time ? This does not happen when I just retrieve an histogram without acquisition.
Outlook
Do you have some propositions for improvements or an alternative ? I can still work with the HSPT function for the moment but using binary should save me a lot of time.
Edit 1 (print(repr(data)))
I print(repr(data)) just after the query. Here are the first lines that come out.
'\x1e\x00\x00\x001\x00\x00\x00+\x00\x00\x00*\x00\x00\x00)\x00\x00\x00+\x00\x00\x00$\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00"\x00\x00\x00$\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00&\x00\x00\x00$\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x007\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00!\x00\x00\x00#\x00\x00\x00&\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x00\r\n'

'%\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x00*\x00\x00\x00)\x00\x00\x00,\x00\x00\x00)\x00\x00\x00\'\x00\x00\x00!\x00\x00\x006\x00\x00\x00/\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x1d\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x00)\x00\x00\x00"\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x00#\x00\x00\x00!\x00\x00\x00$\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x00,\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x00#\x00\x00\x00\r\n'

'\x18\x00\x00\x00!\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x00"\x00\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x00"\x00\x00\x00\'\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x003\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x00!\x00\x00\x00%\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x00\x1b\x00\x00\x00"\x00\x00\x002\x00\x00\x001\x00\x00\x00%\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00%\x00\x00\x00!\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00$\x00\x00\x00\r\n'

'\x1d\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x00"\x00\x00\x00\x1d\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\'\x00\x00\x00"\x00\x00\x00*\x00\x00\x00\'\x00\x00\x00%\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00)\x00\x00\x00)\x00\x00\x00\'\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x00"\x00\x00\x00\'\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00"\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x00#\x00\x00\x00\x1a\x00\x00\x00\'\x00\x00\x00\r\n'

Previously it was
"\x14\x00\x00/\x00=\x00\x00\x00'\x00\x00\x00#\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x00&\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00'\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00*\x00\x00\x00#\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x00!\x00\x00\x00$\x00\x00\x00,\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00,\x00\x00\x00'\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00'\x00\x00\x00*\x00\x00\x00$\x00\x00\x00,\x00\x00\x00\r\n"
b"\x14\x00\x00\x00=\x00\x00\x00'\x00\x00\x00#\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x00&\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00'\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00*\x00\x00\x00#\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x00!\x00\x00\x00$\x00\x00\x00,\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00,\x00\x00\x00'\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00'\x00\x00\x00*\x00\x00\x00$\x00\x00\x00,\x00\x00\x00"
"0\x00\x00\x006\x00\x00\x00*\x00\x00\x00%\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00+\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x004\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x005\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x00#\x00\x00\x00!\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x00)\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00'\x00\x00\x00#\x00\x00\x00+\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x00*\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x00\x00\r\n"

Edit 2
Following comment from @ukBaz I do print(TAC.read_termination). The output is None.
Then I do
for j in range(0,10):
            TAC.write(f'XHST? {j}')
            values = TAC.read_bytes(102)
            print(f'[{j}]: {values}')

You can see there are 10 outputs, binary, with termination \r\n. The last three outputs are mostly zeros which is expected anyway.
[0]: b'6\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x00\x00r\x00\x00\x00|\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00r\x00\x00\x00x\x00\x00\x00\x16\x00\x00\x00v\x00\x00\x00v\x00\x00\x00\x7f\x00\x00\x00g\x00\x00\x00r\x00\x00\x00x\x00\x00\x00y\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00`\x00\x00\x00b\x00\x00\x00|\x00\x00\x00p\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00j\x00\x00\x00\r\n'
[1]: b'x\x00\x00\x00]\x00\x00\x00j\x00\x00\x00`\x00\x00\x00f\x00\x00\x00l\x00\x00\x00c\x00\x00\x00\\\x00\x00\x00[\x00\x00\x00[\x00\x00\x00a\x00\x00\x00o\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00]\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00c\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00r\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00n\x00\x00\x00W\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\r\n'
[2]: b'o\x00\x00\x00l\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x7f\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00n\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00o\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00o\x00\x00\x00h\x00\x00\x00j\x00\x00\x00\x7f\x00\x00\x00\\\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00o\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00p\x00\x00\x00}\x00\x00\x00c\x00\x00\x00{\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00j\x00\x00\x00q\x00\x00\x00\r\n'
[3]: b'|\x00\x00\x00p\x00\x00\x00\\\x00\x00\x00o\x00\x00\x00m\x00\x00\x00]\x00\x00\x00g\x00\x00\x00v\x00\x00\x00g\x00\x00\x00c\x00\x00\x00O\x00\x00\x00k\x00\x00\x00[\x00\x00\x00a\x00\x00\x00n\x00\x00\x00c\x00\x00\x00S\x00\x00\x00h\x00\x00\x00`\x00\x00\x00w\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00S\x00\x00\x00w\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00V\x00\x00\x00\r\n'
[4]: b'j\x00\x00\x00v\x00\x00\x00v\x00\x00\x00q\x00\x00\x00q\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00u\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00q\x00\x00\x00{\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00f\x00\x00\x00v\x00\x00\x00{\x00\x00\x00j\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00i\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00m\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\r\n'
[5]: b'z\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00r\x00\x00\x00y\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00h\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00|\x00\x00\x00k\x00\x00\x00k\x00\x00\x00p\x00\x00\x00p\x00\x00\x00g\x00\x00\x00Z\x00\x00\x00p\x00\x00\x00a\x00\x00\x00]\x00\x00\x00k\x00\x00\x00~\x00\x00\x00c\x00\x00\x00i\x00\x00\x00m\x00\x00\x00b\x00\x00\x00c\x00\x00\x00\r\n'
[6]: b'o\x00\x00\x00}\x00\x00\x00^\x00\x00\x00r\x00\x00\x00z\x00\x00\x00{\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00k\x00\x00\x00Z\x00\x00\x00y\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00{\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00q\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00p\x00\x00\x00w\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x7f\x00\x00\x00o\x00\x00\x00h\x00\x00\x00g\x00\x00\x00\r\n'
[7]: b'j\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00p\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\r\n'
[8]: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\r\n'
[9]: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\r\n'


Edit 3 (new function from pyvisa)
Checking the documentation of pyvisa I found this function query_binary_values that is devoted to query of binary, that returns a list of numbers. It works for extraction and give a result close to the expected but there is always some values that are completely messed up. Either they are too close to 0 or too high by few orders of magnitude.
for j in range(0,10):
        data = TAC.query_binary_values("XHST? "+str(j)+";*WAI",
                          datatype='i',
                          is_big_endian=False,
                          data_points=25,
                          header_fmt = 'empty', expect_termination = True)

The result is shown below as an histogram, and also the output of both TAC.write(f'XHST? {j}') ; print(f'[{j}]: {TAC.read_bytes(102)}') and print(data). In the histogram you can recognize the periodic pattern but you have some very low value in the middle and some huge values. Sometimes those huge values shows up several time and it looks like they are periodic.

[62, 14, 36, 11, 12, 12, 7, 123, 122, 111, 15, 112, 120, 103, 110, 95, 115, 87, 90, 93, 68, 95, 85, 76, 95]
[88, 74, 95, 100, 75, 88, 85, 76, 89, 91, 87, 94, 102, 117, 94, 116, 113, 124, 125, 120, 0, 125, 7, 117, 127]
[108, 123, 122, 1, 6, 2, 116, 23, 23, 21, 123, 24, 0, 7, 34, 20, 112, 9, 121, 6, 121, 2, 112, 106, 103]
[94, 107, 89, 114, 90, 105, 84, 96, 70, 71, 69, 87, 84, 97, 81, 87, 102, 107, 93, 107, 82, 108, 105, 112, 87]
[103, 115, 122, 106, 118, 105, 124, 112, 127, 113, 100, 112, 4, 3, 2, 4, 10, 119, 0, 35, 125, 20, 23, 10, 4]
[2573, 131072, 262144, 393216, 7929856, 8060928, 65536, 8126464, 7274496, 7471104, 6881280, 5242880, 6094848, 5767168, 6750208, 5570560, 5308416, 5373952, 5570560, 6422528, 4784128, 7012352, 6750208, 5898240, 5963776]
[168624128, 101, 94, 107, 83, 117, 115, 110, 111, 102, 116, 3, 118, 10, 121, 0, 126, 117, 106, 119, 122, 117, 108, 15, 101]
[30, 8325645, 1835008, 917504, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 168624128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 2573, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Edit 4
Here is the first numbers retrieved as ascii
'4.4E1'
'1.13E2'
'1.14E2'
'1.18E2'
'1.31E2'
'1.31E2'
'1.20E2'

and their equivalent in binary
,x00\x00\x00
q\x00\x00\x00
r\x00\x00\x00
v\x00\x00\x00
\x03\x00\x00\x00
\x03\x00\x00\x00
x\x00\x00\x00

The output of my program for those numbers is 44, 113, 114, 118, 3, 3, 120.
As you notice, '1.31E2' is represented by \x03\x00\x00\x00 which is transformed into 3. By the query_binary_values function ? I want to understand why it is so. I thought with a 4 byte integer I would be able to represent numbers much bigger than 127 ...


Things would be easier to diagnose if you could print(repr(data)) immediately after the TAC.query(). I suspect that the binary data is getting misread as CRLF terminators at some point. Also why do you need the "WAIT 2" command at the start?

@quamrana I added the result of print(repr(data)) in Edit 1. The wait was here because I tested so many things, especially delays and time.sleep() to slow down the query. Maybe the , are interpreted as CRLF ?

Are you sure that was right? The first two lines of data in your edit should be equivalent, except there is an extra "/" a few characters in. Also, the second line is exactly 100 bytes, so that one would convert perfectly.

@quamrana sorry probably a wrong input on the keyboard. I have update the Edit with another run of the program. Surprisingly it looks a bit different. the 'b' have disappeared. But at least they look long enough everytime I run the program.

(I see you added your own " at the beginning and end of the pasted data - don't do that please). All that data looks ok. Perhaps to guard from accidental missing data, perhaps you could just do: if len(data) == 100: data = struct.unpack("<25i", data)

I understand but I can't afford to skip some data from the experiment. My question is then, if the 'raw' data is fine then where is the problem ? It is maybe encode() that messes up ? The reading fails when data is non-zero. So maybe encode() fails due to (, #, + \t, " ... showing up in the data ?

It is very difficult to tell, but I doubt that encode is the problem. I suspect a timing issue, or maybe the implicit read() might see CRLF in the data and stop too early.

As you are going around the "XHST?" for loop 10 times, I would expect to see print(repr(data)) output 10 lines from the 10 histogram sections queried. Why does your output not show that? Maybe have the print line as print(f"[{j}]: {repr(data)}") to make it clear what is being printed in each loop

I suspect the code in your question is not really the code you are running as it would not run with a NameError: name 'self' is not defined

"The reading fails when data is non-zero" - As @quamrana has mentioned twice, a simple transfer scheme for "binary data" that employs ASCII End-of-Line characters is prone to message/line alignment issues unless there is a way to 'escape' data that matches the EOL chars. Everything is rosy when the data is all zeros (no matches to the EOL), but when there's real data, reading "lines" is no longer reliable.

The instrument is sending the termination characters of \r\n or, as hex, \xOA\xOD. It might be worth doing a print(TAC.read_termination) to check that pyVISA is looking for the correct termination character sequence. Printing the returned values first should show if there are additional \r\n sequences in the data. As further debug, instead of TAC.query("XHST? "+str(j)) you could replace it with TAC.write(f'XHST? {j}'); values = TAC.read_bytes(102); print(f'[{j}]: {values}') and see what raw bytes are sent.

I don't use Python, but doesn't the serial readline function use just the newline character as the EOL? IOW looking for "additional \r\n sequences in the data" is irrelevant. Look for just \n values.

@sawdust. The OP is using pyVISA library which is adding functionality beyond a plain python readline as it trying to help users read the VISA implementation on lab equipment. The particular piece of equipment used by the OP has the termination sequence of \r\n on data it is sending.

@ukBaz I truncated to only few lines not to put too many things but will edit the initial post (see Edit 2). And about the self it is indeed a remnant of the bigger code I use. I made it MWE here, self.TAC_address = 'ASRL8::INSTR'.

@ukBaz @quamrana I have added the result from another function from pyvisa, query_binary_values. It sort of work but there are some weird values in the result. Why is this result so different from the 'built-in' function 'HSPT' ? Maybe the problem is the connection from the TAC to the computer ? It is a serial that is transformed into a USB through 2 adapters, then it is connected to a USB hub that goes to the computer. Is it not too much convoluted ?

I think there are two things going on here. 1) When you open_resource you need to include read_termination='\r\n' for the query_binary_values to work correctly as you appear to be getting \r\n in the middle of the rows. You don't see this with the read_bytes experiment. 2) Your plot doesn't look like a histogram to me. Even with the read_bytes data I can't get a line plot in matplotlib to look like your first one which I'm assuming is a screen grab from the MODEL SR620 Universal Time Interval Counter. Are you requesting the correct data?

@ukBaz 1) adding parameter read_termination='\r\n' to query_binary_values did not help remove those weird values. 2) About the histograms, they are made using matplotlib.pyplot.step, using the 250 data points for vertical axis (horizontal axis is known from the frequency reference given to the SR620).

Turns out the low values shows up when the result is above 127. The communication is set to 8 bits so why is it limited to 127 ? I try to find out now. I found this comparing the binary and the ascii output.
